# Echoing post from query in function.php

Tags: php, ajax, loops, post, echo

I want to implement an ajax post filter based on category and found this which works: https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/ajax-post-filters.html
The only thing is that I would like the post output from function.php to be different. Originally it is just:

```
echo '<h2>' . $query->post->post_title . '</h2>';
```

but I want to use my own post loop configuration:

```
<div <?php post_class( 'front-post-small col-front' ); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( the_permalink() ); ?>">
            <div class="front-post-img"> 
                <?php the_post_thumbnail( array(756,512) ); ?>
                <div class="post-caption">
                    <h3 class="text-uppercase front-post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                </div>                     
            </div>                 
        </a>             
    </div>
```

I have tried passing it with echo, but it either doesn't work at all or the classes and links are printed instead of producing links and css.

Comment: You need to use `<?php echo ...` or `<?= ...` both of which do the same job, `<?=` is shorthand for `echo`/`print`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but do you mean just passing my whole loop after <?php echo or line for line? I need to alter the post code as well right or put it in ''. Cant get it to work anyway.

Comment: Getting error on the first line: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /homepages/34/d715953478/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/aktueltspania/functions.php on line 720

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
echo    '<div class="front-post-small col-front">';
           echo    '<a href="' .  get_permalink()  . '">';
           echo    '<div class="front-post-img">';
       echo    '<img' . the_post_thumbnail( array(756,512) ) . '>';

           echo    '<h3 class="text-uppercase front-post-title post-caption">' . $query->post->post_title . '</h3>';

           echo    '</div>';
           echo    '</a>'; 
           echo    '</div>';
```